# What is the difference between <type>variable and variable as type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In Typescript there is two way to cast objects.

```
<type>variable
```

and

```
variable as type
```

Both of these seems to be permanent (compile-time) casting so the casted object will retain it's type. E.g:

```
let number: number = 2;

let string1 = <string>number;
let string2 = number as string;

string1; // -> the type is string
string1; // -> the type is string
```

My question: What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two?

They are identical. `x as Y` was later created as an alternative syntax for `<Y>x` to enable non-ambiguous type-assertions in TSX files (as `<Y>x` would be otherwise recognized as a JSX expression). The `x as Y` syntax is preferred.

---

However, you have an apparent misconception here. This is not type-casting, but a compile-time type-*assertion*. The difference between the two is best demonstrated by what happens at runtime:

```
let number: number = 2;
let string = number as string;

console.log(typeof string); // "number"
```

TypeScript does not have a runtime framework to do automatic type-casting and type-checking, this is a design goal. *(seriously?)*

Comment: Yeah, I know its only compile-time, wrong wording from my part.

Answer (score 4):

They are both the same. the `foo as` string syntax was introduced to avoid ambiguity with JSX syntax (commonly used with React).

More information [here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#as-foo-vs.-less-than-foo-greater-than)

Answer (score 3):

As quoted from Basarat Ali Syed's book, TypeScript Deep Dive:

> `as foo` vs. `<foo>`
>
> Originally the syntax that was added was `<foo>`. This is demonstrated
> below:

```
var foo: any
var bar = <string> foo; // bar is now of type "string"
```

> However there is an ambiguity in the language grammar when
> using `<foo>` style assertions in JSX: `var foo = <string>bar; </string>`
> Therefore it is now recommended that you just use as foo for
> consistency.

[TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#as-foo-vs.-less-than-foo-greater-than)